# Referencing from table with mixed cells of different categories

Tags: filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to program a Google Sheets for comparing and analyzing logistic costs. 
I have the following:

- A sheet with a database of numbers, organized like this:

[image: DATABASE]

- A second sheet with a table in which, using the `MIN` function, I get the price of the cheapest provider for each model, depending on quantity and destination.

[image: MINIMUM PRICE]

- And last, into another sheet, I have what I call "The interface". Using an `INDEX MATCH MATCH` formula, I let the user choose destination and quantity for each one of the models avalable, and it returns the cheapest price. (I can't post more images, so basically it has this structure):

  ```
  MODEL A  
  DESTINATION:    DESTINATION 2  
  NUM. OBJ:       2  
  PRICE:          59  
  PROVIDER:
  ```

My problem is that I can't figure how to make it return the name of the provider with the cheapest price, as I'm referencing from the second table, in which in a same row or column there are cells with prices that belong to different providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `min` is undesirable in this context, because it doesn't tell you *where* the minimal value was found, and you need this information.

Here is a formula that returns the minimal cost together with the provider. In my example, the data is in the range A1:E7, as below; destination is in G1 and model is in G2.

[image: sample data]

```
=iferror(array_constrain(sort({filter(A1:A7, B1:B7=G2), filter(filter(C1:E7, B1:B7=G2), C1:E1=G1)}, 2, True), 1, 2), "Not found")
```

The same with linebreaks for readability:

```
=iferror(
   array_constrain(
     sort(
       {
         filter(A1:A7, B1:B7 = G2), 
         filter(filter(C1:E7, B1:B7 = G2), C1:E1 = G1)
        }, 
     2, True), 
   1, 2), 
"Not found")
```

Explanation:

1. filtering by B1:B7 = G2 means keeping only the rows with the desired model
2. filtering by C1:E1 = G1 means keeping only the column with desired destination
3. { , } means putting two parts of a filtered table together: column A, and column with destination
4. sort by 2nd column (price), in ascending order (true)
5. `array_constrain` keeps only the first row in this sort; that is, one with lowest price.
6. `iferror` is in case there is no such destination or model in the table. Then the function returns "not found".

Example: with G1 = Destination 1 and G2 = A, the formula returns

```
 Provider 2     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to replace the {,} with {\} but after that it worked perfectly !!